# Python doesn't consider character "c" in a string

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have a string like this:

`mystring="Clusterd695c_ROUGE1.csv"`

When I use `mystring.rstrip("_ROUGE1.csv")`, I expect to return `"Clusterd695c"`, but I get `"Clusterd695"`. As if the last character "c" has not been seen.This only happens for character "c" and the other characters works true. Like this:

```
mystring="Clusterd695f_ROUGE1.csv"
mystring.rstrip("_ROUGE1.csv")
```

Then I get `"Clusterd695f"`, that was expecting.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit surprising to me but the issue is that `rstrip`, when provided a string, will treat that string as a set and remove characters from the end of the string until they do not belong to that set. Because there's a 'c' in the newly-created set (i.e., **c**sv), it removes the 'c' at the end too, stopping at '5' because it doesn't belong to the string "_ROUGE1.csv".

One way to deal with this is to use a replace: `mystring.replace("_ROUGE1.csv", "")`; another option is to simply chop off the last `len("_ROUGE1.csv")` characters. One caveat with the `replace` approach is that it will replace that string *anywhere* in the string, so `"_ROUGE1.csv_ROUGE1.csv".replace("_ROUGE1.csv", "") == ""`

Comment: The `strip()` functions always worked that way (i. .e considering its argument as character set), so I don't understand the surprise. In the given use case its simply the wrong function to call.

Comment: Yes, ```mystring.replace("_ROUGE1.csv","")``` solved the problem.

Comment: @guidot because to wit it doesn't work like this in any other language. :-) Automatically coercing to a (logical) set is definitely not explicit (per zen). The `help` entry for `str.strip` doesn't explicitly mention this behavior, either (at least in 3.6.10). Therefore I find it a bit surprising.

Comment: @erip: Given, that there is no type character set, I find the description *If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead* clear enough. The [help file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) is a bit better, however: *The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed* and has an example very similar to that of the question.

Comment: There is type `set`, but we digress. :-)